# Issues with naming ranges for charts within the Google Spreadsheet Script

Tags: charts, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I've been trying for days to create charts with an intelligent range, that differs when the data in the google spreadsheet is updated. However i succeeded doing so, i can't get the .setOption aspect to work. I want for example, a title, description etc with the chart. But this is not the main issue since i can insert there by hand.

More important however is the range name, because there isn't when i use the script. So, within the chart it is not possible to see what each column represents, and i really want to fix that. I tried to use the .setNamedRange() aspects, but that is not working.

Someone who can help me with that?

```
function check() {

 var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
    var end = sheet.getLastRow();
    var start = (end - 5); 
    var endnew = (end - 4);
    var startnew = (end - 6);

     if(sheet.getCharts().length == 0){    
     Logger.log("Er is geen grafiek");
     var chartBuilder = sheet.newChart()
     .asColumnChart().setStacked()
     .addRange(sheet.getRange("A" + startnew + ":" + "A" + endnew)) // should have a name
     .addRange(sheet.getRange("B" + startnew + ":" + "B" + endnew)) // should have a name
     .addRange(sheet.getRange("E" + startnew + ":" + "E" + endnew)) //should have a name
     .setOption('title', 'Effectief gebruik kantoorruimte') //not working
     .setPosition(10, 10, 0, 0)

     var chart = chartBuilder.build();
     sheet.insertChart(chart);    
  }

  else{
Logger.log("Er is wel een grafiek");
var charts = sheet.getCharts();
for (var i in charts) {
  var chart = charts[i];
  var ranges = chart.getRanges();
  var builder = chart.modify();
  for (var j in ranges) {
    var range = ranges[j];
    builder.removeRange(range);

    builder
    .addRange(sheet.getRange("A" + (start) + ":" + "A" + end)) //should have a name
    .addRange(sheet.getRange("B" + (start) + ":" + "B" + end)) //should have a name
    .addRange(sheet.getRange("E" + (start) + ":" + "E" + end))  // should have a name
    .setOption('title', 'Effectief gebruik kantoorruimte')
    .build();
    sheet.updateChart(builder.build());  

   }
    }
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that this code is the issue?

```
builder
.addRange(sheet.getRange("A" + (start) + ":" + "A" + end))
```

Maybe try using the JavaScript `toString()` method to make sure that your text formula is working.

```
.addRange(sheet.getRange("A" + start.toString() + ":" + "A" + end.toString()))
```

There is a different format that you can use:

```
getRange(row, column, numRows, numColumns)
```

So, it would be:

```
getRange(start, 1, 1, numColumns)
```

That starts on row "start" in column A.  It gets one row of data, and how ever many number of columns.